# Module problems Python MacOS 10.15.3

Tags: python

I have problems getting the Cleantext module for Python to work. 
First, the module could not be found, but I fixed that by copying the cleantext folder to /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/.
 
However, now I get the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>  
>    File "exercise3.py", line 43, in  
>  
>      cleaned_text = custom_clean(orig_text) 
>  
>    File "exercise3.py", line 40, in custom_clean 
>  
>    replace_with_number='',) 
>  
>   TypeError: clean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lower'

Suspecting it had something to do with the string module, I also tried moving this with no luck. 
Lastly, tried setting up an anaconda environment, but got stuck as it did not seem as if my shell would init conda.